# How to change the datatype of the String args[] in Main of java

Tags: java

The default parameter for main() is always (String[] arg).  When i change this to (Int arg) i get a run time error "no such method error". I know the error is caused by changing the parameter.

My question is can I change the parameter from a String array to something else ?

Or i must always use the default, and then cast it to int using Integer.parseInt() !

Comment: Note that `parseInt()` doesn't do a cast. A `String` is impossibly a superclass or subclass of `int`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The signature of the main method is fixed, you cannot change it.

You will need to convert the arguments from a string to an integer.